# Prove that the order of the preimage of N is the order of the kernel times the order of N.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I cannot seem to make any progress at all with this proof. Suggestions and hints. No full proofs, please. Thanks!

Suppose $\phi:G\to G'$ is a homomorphism of finite groups, and define $K=\ker(\phi)$.  If $|K|=k$ and $N$ is a subgroup 
of $G'$, show that
$$
\left|\phi^{-1}(N)\right|=k\cdot|N|
$$
That is, prove that for every $n\in N$, there are precisely $k$ elements in $G$ that map to $n$. One might say in this case that 
$\phi$ is a $k$-to-one homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using first theorem of isomorphism and Lagrange theorem. Notice that $K$ is a subgroup of $(\phi)^{-1}(N)$

Answer (score 1):

This was 2015 and the question shows up in search results, so it's time for a full proof.

The statement is not true (in general) if $\phi$ is not surjective. Consider the embedding. $\mathbb Z_2\to \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ of finite abelian groups. $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ has order $4$, its preimage has order $2$, and the kernel has order $1$.

In the case of a canonical quotient $\pi: G \to G/N$ the statement is clearly true. $\pi$ sends cosets of size $|N|$ to points, so for each subset $S$ of $G/N$ one gets $|\pi^{–1}(S)| = |S|\, |N|$. Let $\phi: G \to H$ be a surjective morphism of finite groups. The first isomorphism theorem states that $\phi$ is, up to composition with an isomorphism, a canonical quotient map as above, and the result follows immediately.